# How to set click event of shape(ART) area in react native?

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-animatable, react-native-svg

I need write click event of particular Shape which draw using react native ART. How can i achieve this ?
can you please share your ideas or thought on this so can i worked on it.

```
 sectionAngles.map(section => (
                <Group>                

                <TouchableWithoutFeedback                  
                  onPress={this.bindCallBackClick}>
                  <View>
                  <Shape
                    key={section.index}
                    d={path(section)}
                    fill={section.data.color}
                    strokeWidth={1} />

                  <ART.Text font={{ fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue', fontSize: 20, }}
                    fill="#000"
                    x={path.centroid(section)[0]}
                    y={path.centroid(section)[1]}
                    ellipsizeMode={"middle"}
                    alignment="center"
                  >{section.data.itemName}</ART.Text>
                  </View></TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </Group>

              ))
```